# How to create static class constant variable from another constant variable?

Tags: php

I have a constant called PREFIX defined in constants.php. In class Foo, I would like to create a static class constant with PREFIX as the prefix. But I get a syntax error on that const definition line.

```
require_once 'constants.php';

class Foo {
    const FOO_CONST = PREFIX . 'bar';

    public function __construct() {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Unless you define another constant there, and use it in the class: `define('BAR_CONST', PREFIX . 'bar');` and then `const FOO_CONST = BAR_CONST;`

Comment: Are you kidding? Global variables ? Where?

Comment: `define` basically has all the downfalls of global variables

Comment: So why are you using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP a `const` must be a value, not an expression.
So `const FOO_CONST = 'foo' . 'bar';` won't work either.

You have to use `define` or a class member that gets initialized in the constructor instead of a `const`. Initializing a class member outside a class method with an expression does not work either.